# How can I copy and excel sheet to a new workbook using the print range as the source

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA how can I copy an Excel sheet to a new workbook using the sheets print range as the cell range to copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Yourworksheet` is the worksheet with your data that you will have to declare accordingly.

```
Dim PrintZone As String

PrintZone = Yourworksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea

Yourworksheet.Range(PrintZone).Copy

Workbooks.Add

ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Glad to help! Could you validate my answer then? Thanks